# Amazon Cognito Google auth Invalid login token

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-authentication

This issue has been bugging me for days,I am using Amazon cognito and Google as one of my external identity providers. I have configured the identity pool on Amazon using the client id from my project on Google developers and is using GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context,account,scope) to retrieve my token.

I retrieve the token okay but when I submit it to Amazon, it throws this exception every time despite changing the clien ids

Exception Invalid login token. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 5474cbb8-03e6-11e5-87eb-310fb7652b97)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to diagnose the problem without looking at your actual code. Based on what you said, you are using the correct method (GoogleAuthUtil.getToken) to extract the token.

Here is a link to our documentation on Google Integration:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/google/

Take a look at the documentation to ensure you have set up google correctly, configured your identity pool correctly, and are passing in the correct arguments to the method(s).

If this does not solve the issue, please follow up with some code samples showing how you extract the token and set the logins map.

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem while using Cognito and Google authentication in NodeJS.

Google returns `access_token`, `refresh_token` and `id_token`, out of which `id_token` need to be passed to Cognito.